# Does an $A\times B$ matrix of $a\times b$ matrices constitute a single $(Aa)\times (Bb)$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, notation

Does an $A\times B$ matrix of $a\times b$ matrices constitute a single $(Aa)\times (Bb)$ matrix?

Here is what I mean:

> $$\boldsymbol{M}=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> \boldsymbol{m}(1,1) & \cdots & \boldsymbol{m}(1,B) \\
> \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
> \boldsymbol{m}(A,1) & \cdots & \boldsymbol{m}(A,B) \\
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> $$\boldsymbol{m}(x,y)=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> c^{(x,y)}_{(1,1)} & \cdots & c^{(x,y)}_{(1,b)} \\
> \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
> c^{(x,y)}_{(a,1)} & \cdots & c^{(x,y)}_{(a,b)} \\
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> $A$, $B$, $a$ and $b$ and all $c$ are all real numbers. (Sorry if the notation for $c$ is strange; it seemed the least awkward way to attach four coordinates to the value.)

Which of the following is true?

$$\boldsymbol{M}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c^{(1,1)}_{(1,1)} & \cdots & c^{(1,1)}_{(1,b)} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c^{(1,1)}_{(a,1)} & \cdots & c^{(1,1)}_{(a,b)} \\
\end{pmatrix} 
& \cdots 
& \begin{pmatrix}
c^{(1,B)}_{(1,1)} & \cdots & c^{(1,B)}_{(1,b)} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c^{(1,B)}_{(a,1)} & \cdots & c^{(1,B)}_{(a,b)} \\
\end{pmatrix}  \\
\vdots 
& \ddots 
& \vdots \\
\begin{pmatrix}
c^{(A,1)}_{(1,1)} & \cdots & c^{(A,1)}_{(1,b)} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c^{(A,1)}_{(a,1)} & \cdots & c^{(A,1)}_{(a,b)} \\
\end{pmatrix}  
& \cdots 
& \begin{pmatrix}
c^{(A,B)}_{(1,1)} & \cdots & c^{(A,B)}_{(1,b)} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c^{(A,B)}_{(a,1)} & \cdots & c^{(A,B)}_{(a,b)} \\
\end{pmatrix}  \\
\end{bmatrix} \tag{1}$$

$$\boldsymbol{M}=
\begin{bmatrix}
c^{(1,1)}_{(1,1)} & \cdots & c^{(1,1)}_{(1,b)} & \cdots & \cdots & c^{(1,B)}_{(1,1)} & \cdots & c^{(1,B)}_{(1,b)} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c^{(1,1)}_{(a,1)} & \cdots & c^{(1,1)}_{(a,b)} & \cdots & \cdots & c^{(1,B)}_{(a,1)} & \cdots & c^{(1,B)}_{(a,b)} \\
\vdots & & \vdots & \ddots & & \vdots & & \vdots \\
\vdots & & \vdots & & \ddots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
c^{(A,1)}_{(1,1)} & \cdots & c^{(A,1)}_{(1,b)} & \cdots & \cdots & c^{(A,B)}_{(1,1)} & \cdots & c^{(A,B)}_{(1,b)} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & & & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c^{(A,1)}_{(a,1)} & \cdots & c^{(A,1)}_{(a,b)} & \cdots & \cdots & c^{(A,B)}_{(a,1)} & \cdots & c^{(A,B)}_{(a,b)} \\
\end{bmatrix} \tag{2}$$

Or are equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ somehow equivalent?

(Here, I am using brackets and parentheses around the matrices interchangeably. I know the double ellipses probably are not technically correct, but it makes the matrix a lot more readable.)

In equation $(1)$, $\boldsymbol M$ has $A$ rows and $B$ columns of elements, but each of those elements is a matrix of its own. In equation $(2)$, $\boldsymbol M$ has $A\cdot a$ rows and $B\cdot b$ columns all of real numbers.

In my mind, I am drawing comparisons to a set of real numbers versus a set of sets of real numbers. This distinction is important—if it was not, then power sets would be indistinguishable from their original sets. I imagine that not making this distinction for matrices would lead to technical errors when performing matrix operations and calculations—for example, calculating a determinant.

I know conventions in the field may be different, as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2421402/347062) evinces.

I believe this *might* also relate to the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Comment: There are several ways how to get a $(Aa)\times (Bb)$ matrix from a $A \times B$ and a $a \times b$ matrix. The kronecker product you have mentioned is one way. It is related to linear maps on tensor products, but the wikipedia article that you have linked says all about that. Well, there are other ways, so I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @S.M.Roch It’s about a notation that I see a lot and what precisely it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is: there is a difference if you want/need there to be and otherwise there isn't. Notationally it's very common to see so-called block matrices written as, e.g.
$$ \begin{bmatrix}A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix}$$
where $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are themselves matrices. Usually the point is just to highlight these blocks as important submatrices.

It's conceivable but unlikely that there might need to be a difference in some situations, though. All of the contexts I can think of will still work if you drop the distinction that the submatrices are instead considered as discrete matrix objects.

Comment: I like that word *submatrix*…

Comment: I apologize for forgetting to come back to this question and select an answer. +25